# Query MySQL by date & first 15

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to understand how to do a MySQL query.  It needs to look at all records, then sort them by date and then only return in $results the first 15 (in order w/ most recent first)

Date field is 'date_version' and it's stored as date and is formatted in database as: yyyy-mm-dd

Simple results showing all - how do I modify it?

```
// get all entries from database table Mytable;
$results = DB::query("SELECT * FROM Mytable");
```

Comment: It works with SQL which is then used by meekroDB. So don't search/ask for meekroDB, just ask about the SQL.

Comment: The duplicate question should answer that to you. If not, please comment here what is unclear about the problem to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be -

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT * FROM Mytable ORDER BY date_version DESC LIMIT 15");
```